# WPF DataGrid Text Gets Cut Off

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

My WPF 4.5 application has a small (but annoying) visual bug where a `DataGrid`'s cells are cut off upon loading:
[image: initial load]
[Dropbox link to the screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5e5p9phctfdb0r/Screenshot%202015-06-30%2009.25.26.png?dl=0)

But once you resize the window (click the square button in the upper right corner) and re-maximize it, the `DataGrid`'s cells appear as they should:
[image: after resizing]
[Dropbox link to the screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iu5qsl9svfb580f/Screenshot%202015-06-30%2009.25.31.png?dl=0)

In the XAML, every column's width is set to `Auto`, except for the "Name" column, which is `*`. Is there anything I can do to prevent this visual bug from happening/is there anything I'm doing that's causing this bug?

Here's my XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Datasets, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Name="dsDatagrid" SelectionMode="Extended" MouseDoubleClick="ViewDataset">
<DataGrid.Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}" TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsWorking}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TargetUpdated">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CollectionChangedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dsDatagrid, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="Auto">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="NameCell" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.BackupSingleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource BackupSingleButtonStyle}" Margin="5 10"/>
                    <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.DeleteSingleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource DeleteSingleButtonStyle}" Margin="5 10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="*">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Source Images" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding SourceImages.Count, StringFormat={}{0:N0}, TargetNullValue=NONE}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Time" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding StartTime, StringFormat={}{0:MM}/{0:dd}/{0:yy} {0:HH}\:{0:mm}\:{0:ss}}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="End Time" Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding EndTime, StringFormat={}{0:MM}/{0:dd}/{0:yy} {0:HH}\:{0:mm}\:{0:ss}, TargetNullValue=In Progress}"/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="Auto">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

If it's relevant, here's my `DataGrid` style:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BannerNormalBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="24 10"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="24 0"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TextBlockDisabledForegroundBrushDark}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Border Name="Border" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DataGridRowSelectedBrush}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="{StaticResource DataGridOddRowBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="{StaticResource DataGridEvenRowBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
    <Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserSortColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="EnableRowVirtualization" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode" Value="Recycling"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Not sure if intended or even if it has any impact on the bug but it looks like `ID` is also `Width="*"`.

Comment: Thanks, @Vlad; that was an oversight on my part. It didn't impact the end result, but it was an oversight nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't really tried your code, but just by looking at it, I have a hunch...

StackPanels tend to have problems calculating their available space, so your problem may be caused by the StackPanel inside your column's DataTemplate, that is unable to communicate its size correctly to the column on load.

My suggestion is to change the StackPanel for another Panel. In this case, a good old Grid would work just fine, and I bet you won't see any glitch this time.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="Auto">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Name="NameCell" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.BackupSingleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource BackupSingleButtonStyle}" Margin="5 10"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.DeleteSingleCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource DeleteSingleButtonStyle}" Margin="5 10"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't fix the issue :-\